# Integer leading zero issue in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a very simple Java program :

```
class test {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {  
        int i = 23;    
        int j = i/10;   
        System.out.println ("Value of i: " +i);
        System.out.println ("Value of j: " +j);
    }    
}
```

The output is as expected - `i = 23` and `j = 2`

Now, I kept changing the value of `i` in the program. And the output started to change.

The value of `i = 02` and the output becomes - `i = 2` and `j = 0`

The value of `i = 023` and the output becomes - `i = 19` and `j = 1`

Now I am confused. When I gave the value of `i = 023` in the program, in the output I expected to get  `i = 23` and `j = 2`. But why is `i` becoming `19`?

Answer (score 6):

023 is treated as octal (8) base. 023 in base 8 is 19 in decimal base.

Answer (score 4):

In Java Numbers Starting With 0 treated Octal Numbers i.e. base 8.

```
 class Octal{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     int six=06;      //Equal to decimal 6
     int seven=07;    //Equal to decimal 7
     int eight=010;   //Equal to decimal 8
     int nine=011;    //Equal to decimal 9
     System.out.println("Octal 010 :"+eight);
   }
 }
```

Output is:
Octal 010 :8

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a zero before a number(023), you are actually converting it to octal. And here you are trying to view the output as decimal. So you are getting the decimal equivalent of that input octal.