# Is there a work around for using a leading zero for a password "0123" in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, integer, leading-zero

This password has been used for many years so I cannot change it without ire from employees. The original code was done in Java which allows a leading zero. Is there any way I can still use the password "0123" in Kotlin? I have the password saved as a variable.

Tried 0123 and it gives the error: Unsupported [Literal prefixes and suffixes] & Property Setter and Getter expected.

I expected it to work as it works without a 0 in front.

Usage:

```
private var password = 0123
private var passcode: EditText? = null

if (passcode?.text.toString() == password.toString()) {
// do something
}else {
// do something else
}
```

Comment: Password for what? It's not at all clear what you're talking about.

Comment: What type is the password? Strings can have leading 0s, although [it's not good to store passwords in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937641/handling-passwords-used-for-auth-in-source-code). Whatever the case, it sounds like your password-handing code is seriously insecure, so you may have larger problems than just leading zeroes.

Comment: Edittext. User enters 0123 and it validates.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's still unclear what we're dealing with here.

Comment: @ggorlen This usage does not need to be that secure for this usage.

Comment: We need to see sample code to understand what you're trying to do and what you're doing incorrectly. For example, show your working Java code and your not-working Kotlin version.

Comment: added code above

Comment: If it's a String, enter it as a String. You would have the same issue if you declared an `int` in Java. Use `private var password = "0123"`

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't have the working Java code. I am making a new app and the users are acclimated to using the passcode 0123 for this use case.

Comment: Why are you defining the password as a number and not a string?

Comment: @Altohombre "This usage does not need to be that secure for this usage." —every company that got hacked. I hope you're not working for LastPass or [SolarWinds](https://www.cnn.com/2021/02/26/politics/solarwinds123-password-intern/index.html).

Comment: @ggorlen this is an internal use app and even if someone guessed it it wouldn't be a big deal. Just a deterent for new people.

Comment: Probably a dupe of [Integer leading zero issue in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710650/integer-leading-zero-issue-in-java) now that code was added.

Comment: @Altohombre Yeah, it's an internal app right now and not a big deal now. Then later, you quit the company, someone forgets that it's totally insecure and puts some important information in there and it becomes exposed to the public. Next thing you know, your company is out billions of dollars. It's not hard to sensibly and securely encrypt the password and use a char array rather than an integer. Other people see these sort of posts and think it's OK, so don't be offended that this is pointed out--it's public duty.

Comment: @Tenfour04 your answer worked. I haven't looked at this code in a while and got flustered by the Octal stuff I saw online. Please make an answer so I can give you credit. thx!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should seriously consider *not* hardcoding a password like this. It is very insecure. Now your question might be relevant for other things than passwords, so for those cases please read ahead.

Without double-quotes, the value you're using to set the `password` variable is a number, not a string (text). So essentially you are (trying to) define the number 123 (one hundred and twenty three) as password. But most likely you don't care about the numeric value 123 here, you want the 4 *characters* `0123`.

If what you want is to compare text, use double-quotes like this `private val password = "0123"` (and then you don't need `.toString()` for your comparison).

Now as to why you're getting this weird error. The error you're facing arises if you're trying to use a number literal with a leading 0, like `0123` in Kotlin. This is because Kotlin believes you're trying to use Java's octal prefix interpretation and is preventing a potential mistake. In Java, number literals with a 0 in front are read in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8 number system). So the value `0123` (as a number literal) is in fact `83` in decimal.

Kotlin doesn't support the octal prefix, but that is definitely not what you want here anyway.

Comment: Worth mentioning for future visitors that plain text strings baked into the source code aren't secure, nor is saving the user's password input in a string, so after these changes the authentication system is still completely unsafe.